# How to display iAd Banner with UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ipad, modal-dialog, iad

Any possibility of displaying an iAd banner in a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Reading the documentation there are is no size listed for iPad form sheet:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html

It also says "In the future, additional sizes may be exposed by iAd."

In the meantime, any recommendations on how to handle this?  The form view on iPad will display for a long period of time and is where the ad banner should be.

Searching a bit, I see there's some code to display ads from other network types, in this case "ad mob", in a form view:
https://github.com/navisingh/ad-networks/tree/master/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK

If iAd does not support form sheet, then I guess I could search other networks.

UPDATE: Ad Mob supports sizing as follows...

```
        // Size ad banner to form view width
        CGFloat aWidth = [self view].frame.size.width;
        adMobBannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(aWidth, 60.0f))];
```